# Angular2 AOT styles don't load correctly

Tags: angular, typescript

I have been trying to add styles to my compenent dynamically for a while and nothing works in AOT.  I currently have this but nether of the stylesheets load when built in AOT:

```
import { filt } from './funcs';

@Component({
  selector: 'open-account',
  styleUrls: ['./open-account.component.scss', './open-account-widget-styles.component.scss'].filter(filt),
  templateUrl: './open-account.component.html',
})
```

funcs.js:

```
export function filt(elem, i) {
    if (i === 0) return true;
    if (i === 1 && window.location.href.indexOf('widget=true') > -1) return true;
}
```

Neither of the stylesheets load at all. Why is that and how can I fix this?